# Find all n-dimensional lines and diagonals with NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, diagonal, n-dimensional

Using NumPy, I would like to produce a list of all lines and diagonals of an n-dimensional array with lengths of k.

---

Take the case of the following three-dimensional array with lengths of three.

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

For this case, I would like to obtain all of the following types of sequences. For any given case, I would like to obtain all of the possible sequences of each type. Examples of desired sequences are given in parentheses below, for each case.

- 1D lines

  - x axis (`0, 1, 2`)
  - y axis (`0, 3, 6`)
  - z axis (`0, 9, 18`)
- 2D diagonals

  - x/y axes (`0, 4, 8`, `2, 4, 6`)
  - x/z axes (`0, 10, 20`, `2, 10, 18`)
  - y/z axes (`0, 12, 24`, `6, 12, 18`)
- 3D diagonals

  - x/y/z axes (`0, 13, 26`, `2, 13, 24`)

---

The solution should be generalized, so that it will generate all lines and diagonals for an array, regardless of the array's number of dimensions or length (which is constant across all dimensions).

Comment: What's the significance of the 2 highlighted blocks for the 2D diagonals?  A central diagonal will have 3 items; you are including the anti-diagonal in the same tuple, but somehow separated.  Are you interested in offset diagonals as well?

Comment: Do you want to generate `(0, 1, 2)` and `(2, 1, 0)`?

Comment: Are you trying to implement [this](http://ericwieser.me/games/4d/)?

Comment: @hpaulj They are to demonstrate that I am interested in diagonals going both directions.

Comment: @Eric I do not want to generate both `(0, 1, 2)` and `(2, 1, 0)` - only one or the other. Conceptually, that game's logic is what I'd like to implement, but in a generalized format (for any size or number of dimensions).

Comment: That game generalizes `k` but not n. My answer here generalizes both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This solution generalized over `n`**

Lets rephrase this problem as "find the list of indices".

We're looking for all of the 2d index arrays of the form

```
array[i[0], i[1], i[2], ..., i[n-1]]
```

Let `n = arr.ndim`

Where `i` is an array of shape `(n, k)`

Each of `i[j]` can be one of:

- The same index repeated n times, `ri[j] = [j, ..., j]`
- The forward sequence, `fi = [0, 1, ..., k-1]`
- The backward sequence, `bi = [k-1, ..., 1, 0]`

With the requirements that each sequence is of the form `^(ri)*(fi)(fi|bi|ri)*$` (using regex to summarize it). This is because:

- there must be at least one `fi` so the "line" is not a point selected repeatedly
- no `bi`s come before `fi`s, to avoid getting reversed lines

---

```
def product_slices(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield (
            np.index_exp[np.newaxis] * i +
            np.index_exp[:] +
            np.index_exp[np.newaxis] * (n - i - 1)
        )

def get_lines(n, k):
    """
    Returns:
        index (tuple):   an object suitable for advanced indexing to get all possible lines
        mask (ndarray):  a boolean mask to apply to the result of the above
    """
    fi = np.arange(k)
    bi = fi[::-1]
    ri = fi[:,None].repeat(k, axis=1)

    all_i = np.concatenate((fi[None], bi[None], ri), axis=0)

    # inedx which look up every possible line, some of which are not valid
    index = tuple(all_i[s] for s in product_slices(n))

    # We incrementally allow lines that start with some number of `ri`s, and an `fi`
    #  [0]  here means we chose fi for that index
    #  [2:] here means we chose an ri for that index
    mask = np.zeros((all_i.shape[0],)*n, dtype=np.bool)
    sl = np.index_exp[0]
    for i in range(n):
        mask[sl] = True
        sl = np.index_exp[2:] + sl

    return index, mask
```

---

Applied to your example:

```
# construct your example array
n = 3
k = 3
data = np.arange(k**n).reshape((k,)*n)

# apply my index_creating function
index, mask = get_lines(n, k)

# apply the index to your array
lines = data[index][mask]
print(lines)
```

```
array([[ 0, 13, 26],
       [ 2, 13, 24],
       [ 0, 12, 24],
       [ 1, 13, 25],
       [ 2, 14, 26],
       [ 6, 13, 20],
       [ 8, 13, 18],
       [ 6, 12, 18],
       [ 7, 13, 19],
       [ 8, 14, 20],
       [ 0, 10, 20],
       [ 2, 10, 18],
       [ 0,  9, 18],
       [ 1, 10, 19],
       [ 2, 11, 20],
       [ 3, 13, 23],
       [ 5, 13, 21],
       [ 3, 12, 21],
       [ 4, 13, 22],
       [ 5, 14, 23],
       [ 6, 16, 26],
       [ 8, 16, 24],
       [ 6, 15, 24],
       [ 7, 16, 25],
       [ 8, 17, 26],
       [ 0,  4,  8],
       [ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 0,  3,  6],
       [ 1,  4,  7],
       [ 2,  5,  8],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 13, 17],
       [11, 13, 15],
       [ 9, 12, 15],
       [10, 13, 16],
       [11, 14, 17],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 22, 26],
       [20, 22, 24],
       [18, 21, 24],
       [19, 22, 25],
       [20, 23, 26],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26]])
```

---

Another good set of test data is `np.moveaxis(np.indices((k,)*n), 0, -1)`, which gives an array where every value is its own index

---

I've solved this problem before to implement a [higher dimensional tic-tac-toe](http://ericwieser.me/games/4d/)

Answer (score 3):

```
In [1]: x=np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
```

Selecting individual `rows` is easy:

```
In [2]: x[0,0,:]
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 2])
In [3]: x[0,:,0]
Out[3]: array([0, 3, 6])
In [4]: x[:,0,0]
Out[4]: array([ 0,  9, 18])
```

You could iterate over dimensions with an index list:

```
In [10]: idx=[slice(None),0,0]
In [11]: x[idx]
Out[11]: array([ 0,  9, 18])
In [12]: idx[2]+=1
In [13]: x[idx]
Out[13]: array([ 1, 10, 19])
```

Look at the code for `np.apply_along_axis` to see how it implements this sort of iteration.

Reshape and split can also produce a list of `rows`.  For some dimensions this might require a `transpose`:

```
In [20]: np.split(x.reshape(x.shape[0],-1),9,axis=1)
Out[20]: 
[array([[ 0],
        [ 9],
        [18]]), array([[ 1],
        [10],
        [19]]), array([[ 2],
        [11],
        ...
```

`np.diag` can get diagonals from 2d subarrays

```
In [21]: np.diag(x[0,:,:])
Out[21]: array([0, 4, 8])
In [22]: np.diag(x[1,:,:])
Out[22]: array([ 9, 13, 17])
In [23]: np.diag?
In [24]: np.diag(x[1,:,:],1)
Out[24]: array([10, 14])
In [25]: np.diag(x[1,:,:],-1)
Out[25]: array([12, 16])
```

And explore `np.diagonal` for direct application to the 3d.  It's also easy to index the array directly, with `range` and `arange`, `x[0,range(3),range(3)]`.

As far as I know there isn't a function to step through all these alternatives.  Since dimensions of the returned arrays can differ, there's little point to producing such a function in compiled numpy code.  So even if there was a function, it would step through the alternatives as I outlined.

==============

All the 1d lines

```
x.reshape(-1,3)
x.transpose(0,2,1).reshape(-1,3)
x.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(-1,3)
```

y/z diagonal and anti-diagonal

```
In [154]: i=np.arange(3)
In [155]: j=np.arange(2,-1,-1)
In [156]: np.concatenate((x[:,i,i],x[:,i,j]),axis=1)
Out[156]: 
array([[ 0,  4,  8,  2,  4,  6],
       [ 9, 13, 17, 11, 13, 15],
       [18, 22, 26, 20, 22, 24]])
```

Comment: These functions do not get all sequences for each case. For example, `x[0,0,:]` only retrieves the first row, while it should get `[0, 1, 2]`, `[3, 4, 5]`, ..., `[21, 22, 23]`, `[24, 25, 26]`. The parenthesized sequences in my question are just examples of the desired output.

Comment: I talked about iterating over the various indices needed to get all slices.

Answer (score 2):

np.einsum can be used to build all these kind of expressions; for instance:

```
# 3d diagonals
print(np.einsum('iii->i', a))
# 2d diagonals
print(np.einsum('iij->ij', a))
print(np.einsum('iji->ij', a))
```

Comment: But this does summation, not just slicing

Comment: it only sums over indices that appear on the left but not on the right.